# WiFi interface driver not loading (rtl8192cu driver)

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface

I've been struggling to configure a USB dongle on my linux machine (running debian).

```
$ uname -a
Linux stbede 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can confirm that the device is connected via USB and recognised:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But the driver isn't loading, as per `lsmod`. I am aware that there have been some persistent issues with bugs in this rtl8192cu driver, but it's my understanding that these have been resolved in more recent kernels. However, when I try to load the driver, here's what I get:

```
$ sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:977 command_do() Error running install command for rtlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8192cu': Operation not permitted
```

I'm admittedly a bit mystified about what this error message means. Can anyone advise as to the best course to take troubleshooting this further? I have worked my way through the [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x) for this interface and can confirm that `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek` runs without errors:

```
firmware-realtek is already the newest version (0.43).
```

The [vendor](https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000035492-how-to-resolve-ew-7811un-built-in-driver-issues-in-linux-kernel-v3-10-or-higher) has their [own drivers](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/mw/cufiles/files/download/Driver_Utility/EW-7811Un_Linux_Driver_1.0.1.9.zip) they provide, but these do not want to compile, and seem a bit old (2018) and are just a repackaging of the realtek files used in the rtl8192cu which is part of the kernel.

One last thing, which may be a red herring, but nonetheless bears mentioning.

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms` fails, but linux headers have been successfully installed using `apt-get install` at linux-headers-4.9.0-14-amd64

Comment: `it's my understanding that these have been resolved in more recent kernels` And yet, you are listing a kernel build that's over 2 years old.

Comment: Hmm. Good point. Maybe I should update that.

Comment: Did updating the kernel solve your issue? I am on 6.1.57 and still have issues with rtl8192cu, so I compiled a custom kernel containing the experimental rtl8xxxu driver which at least recognized the device, despite [revealing other problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758940/how-can-i-fix-my-usb-wifi-interface-not-being-detected-after-boot-unless-i-replu). Also see [https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes](this github page) for further information.

Comment: TBH, I just abandoned wifi on the server and went with ethernet. I haven't tried again since then.