# How can I fix my USB WiFi device not being detected after boot unless I replug it and load the driver module manually?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, usb, kernel-modules

**Preamble**

After searching the web and trying several troubleshhoting steps, I now require your help to my quite specific issue with an USB WiFi device:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

This chip should be supported by `rtl8192cu`, however it did not seem to actually be, as it was not detected at all by the OS. I went ahead and compiled a custom kernel including the (experimental) `rtl8xxxu` driver module.

```
# uname -r
6.1.57+rtl8xxxu
```

(The only change compared to the default 6.1.57 kernel was to include the respective driver).

I also did blacklist the alternative driver

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf 
blacklist rtl8192cu
```

and after a reboot (and replugging the USB device, see below) now finally `lsusb` detected it.

During the troubleshooting I also set the option for DMA aggregation and dual-band 2.4 GHz (actually I am not a 100% sure what this does).

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf 
options rtl8xxxu ht40_2g=1 dma_aggregation=1
```

I run Debian 12 with KDE Plasma DE.

**Problem**

Now the problem I am facing is two fold:

- **a) The USB dongle is only detected when I unplug and replug it after each system boot**
  Neither `dmesg` nor `lsusb` display any information about the stick whatsoever until I unplug and replug it. (Note that I encountered the very same behavior with Ubuntu 20.04 + MATE DE before)
- **b) The driver module only seems to work when I load it manually after boot**
  I wanted the driver module to be loaded automatically upon boot, so I added the respective entry to `modules.conf`:

```
# cat /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf 
rtl8xxxu
```

which works in terms of the module being loaded. However, again, the WiFi dongle is not detected at all, ***neither** after I unplug and replug it **nor** after unloading and reloading the driver module using `modprobe` (`-r` respectively)*

Regarding **a)** I assume that the dongle has some kind of energy setting, as this may explain the need to be replugged onto an already booted system. Note that I checked my UEFI ("BIOS") for energy options, and I could not determine any of importance (however, I don't know much about those either).

Regarding **b)** I just feel pain and frustration, as it makes no sense to me at all.

**Questions**

1. How can I force the USB dongle to be detected after boot from software? (Should I to compile the kernel with modular `usbcore/usb_common modules` to reload these after boot?)
2. What possible UEFI ("BIOS") settings exist that may cause the USB dongle to stay undetected after boot?
3. Why the driver doesn't work when loaded upon boot, and how do I troubleshoot and fix this?
4. How could I continue troubleshooting both issues?

Note that I did not include any logs yet but tried to explain the progress I've made. However, if you need specific logs, don't hesitate to name them.

Highly appreciate your help! Much love and happy hackin'

Comment: confused, `rtl8xxxu` **is** included in the linux kernel these days? Why the external repository? I mean, the github repo you link to says, in **BOLD HEADING** that you shouldn't be using the repo on a kernel newer than Linux 4.4?

Comment: debian 6.1.0-13-amd64 did not include the module, neither did 6.1.57 by default, so I had to enable it in the config. It also explicitly stated that it is "experimental". Also, I am not using the repo, the troubleshooting tips just pointed me to that kernel module, that is why I linked it (however, I agree it is not at all relevant, so I edited my post)

Comment: Strange , my system has that module